# How to select TOP 1 results _without_ using LIMIT in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing an SQLite select statement and want to pick out the first hit only that satisfy my criterion. 
My problem is that I'm writing code inside a simulation framework that wraps my SQLite code before sending it to the database, and this wrapping already adds 'LIMIT 100' to the end of the code.
What I want to do:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE a = 0 ORDER BY y LIMIT 1
```

What happens when this simulation development framework has done its job:

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE a = 0 ORDER BY y LIMIT 1 LIMIT 100
exec error near "LIMIT": syntax error
```

So my question is: How do I work around this limitation? Is there any way to still limit my results to give only one hit back despite that the statement will end in 'LIMIT 100'? I'm thinking something like creating a temporary table, add an index and filter on that, but my knowledge is limited to simple database queries.

Comment: Considering my lack of knowledge a simulation framework, try adding comment characters "--" to the end of your query

Comment: You can try a subquery: `select * from (SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE a = 0 ORDER BY y LIMIT 1)` or just a CTE: `with myquery as (SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable WHERE a = 0 ORDER BY y LIMIT 1) select * from myquery`

Comment: The subquery `select * from (select ... limit 1)` works fine and perfectly solves my problem!